# Intersecting Degree 0 Divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

During class today, we were presented quite difficult formulas for computing intersections of divisors.

I'd like to understand this on a more elementary level, what happens when one intersects a degree $0$ divisor $D$ with other divisors/varieties? By intuition I'd say, the resulting divisor has degree $0$ as well?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "degree zero divisor"? 

Comment: A divisor that has $\text{deg }D=0$

Comment: Are you kidding? 

Comment: No, why? I'm guessing by the tone that this is trivially so?

Comment: Simply, it is not clear to me what do you mean by a degree zero divisor. If you simply answer that a degree zero divisor is a divisor of degree zero, it doesn't help so much, what do you think?

Comment: I mean, for example in projective space, if $D=\sum a_i Y_i$ is a formal sum of codimension 1 hypersurfaces $Y_i$ given by some polynomial of degree $d_i$ then the $\text{deg }D = \sum a_i d_i$.

Comment: But this is a quite special case, since the Picard group of the projective space is $\mathbb Z$. How do you want to define the degree in general? 

Comment: Ahh I see. Is it possible to look at the analog, intersecting the first chern class of $\mathcal{O}(D)$ with some other subvariety? Would a trivial first chern class imply that the resulting Divisor has trivial first chern class as well?

Comment: Probably you should think a little bit more about what you really want to ask and then reedit your question accordingly, what do you think?

Comment: Why don't you post one or some of the formulas you want intuition for.  Make sure to include all hypotheses on the schemes and other objects in question.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, in general 'degree' is not so well/uniquely defined.  However, suppose you take a smooth cubic surface in $ \bf{ P}^3$ .  There are 27 lines and they should all have degree 1. Take two lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ which are skew and let $D = l_1-l_2$ .  This will be 'degree zero' with your definition.  Clearly $deg(D|l_1) \neq 0$  Similarly on a quadric hypersurface in $\bf{P}^3$, letting $l_1$ and $l_2$ be two lines which meet , one can construct similar 'examples'.  If $X$ is a variety with $Pic(X) = \bf{Z} $ then what you ask is true.  I would suspect it fails any other time.